# How to make original Grid View on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I would like to implement something like this picture using Grid View or another way by Flutter.

I implemented to use of `GridView.builder` below like codes. But this code doesn't work like the picture.

Could you give me your idea to express like this picture?

```
GridView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
  ),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    final isDoubleWidth = (index + 1) % 5 == 0;
    final itemWidth = isDoubleWidth ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3 * 2 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3;
    return SizedBox(
      width: itemWidth,
      child: Text(item[index].title.toString),
    );
  },
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just use [flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

```
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

StaggeredGrid.count(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  mainAxisSpacing: 4,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4,
  children: const [
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 2,
      mainAxisCellCount: 2,
      child: Tile(index: 0),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 2,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 1),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 2),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 3),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 4,
      mainAxisCellCount: 2,
      child: Tile(index: 4),
    ),
  ],
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`GridView` does not support something like what you have shown in the picture. If you don't want to use 3rd party plugins, I suggest you use `ListView` and `Row` widgets to build this UI. You can consider this UI as a list of rows, and each row would contain either 2 or 3 elements. So based on the index of the `ListView.builder()`'s `itemBuilder` parameter, you can calculate which elements you should show for this list item (the entire row), and from there you can construct your own row using `Row` widget.

Comment: Thank you for your replying. I understand that I have to use Row and ListVIew not using third-party packages. But I cannot imagine it. Could you give me some advice or codes for me?

Comment: I could make it!! I resolve this problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Masaya Yes, using a bit of math, you can do it yourself if you don't want to use 3rd party libraries. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

With this code, I could make that picture likely.

I incremented 5 in this case because the column and row are in 5 items.

```
 final itemLength = (items.length) / 5;

        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: itemLength.toInt(),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              index *= 5;
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 2 / 3,
                        child: Text(items[index].title.toString()),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1 / 3,
                        child: Text(items[index + 1].title.toString()),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1 / 3,
                        child: Text(items[index + 2].title.toString()),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1 / 3,
                        child: Text(items[index + 3].title.toString()),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1 / 3,
                        child: Text(items[index + 4].title.toString()),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              );
            });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).